# Not able to read the item from list using for loop in the jenkins pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Running one linux command and saving the ouput of the command as list and then reding the list item one by one.

```
stage('NAMESPACE Availability') {
            node ('master'){
                  withEnv(["KUBECONFIG=${JENKINS_HOME}/.kube/config"]){
                  NS_list = sh (
                  script: '''kubectl get ns | awk '{print \$1}' | awk '{\$1=\$1; print "[\\x27" $0 "\\x27]"}' FS='\n' OFS="','" RS='' ''',
                  returnStdout: true
                  ).trim()
                  echo "${NS_list}"
                  NS(NS_list)
             }

      }
}
  def NS(list) {
     for (i in list) {
        echo "${i}"
        if ( i == "${NAME_SPACE}" ) {
            sh "kubectl delete all --all -n '${NAME_SPACE}' && kubectl delete '${NAME_SPACE}' "
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Rather then reading as Item its reading as character , Lets say if command output is ['NAME','b2','b6','b7','cert-manager','default'] its reading as below output.

```
[Pipeline] echo
[
[Pipeline] echo
'
[Pipeline] echo
N
[Pipeline] echo
A
[Pipeline] echo
M
[Pipeline] echo
E
[Pipeline] echo

[Pipeline] echo
'
[Pipeline] echo
,
[Pipeline] echo
'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to delete all Namespaces?

Comment: NO, ${NAME_SPACE} is variable, whatever we pass through as parameter , I need add some other condition as well but right now i want to read items in the list as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem as per below changes. Rather then using for(loop).. i used ".contains"

```
stage('NAMESPACE Availability') {
            node ('master'){
                  withEnv(["KUBECONFIG=${JENKINS_HOME}/.kube/config"]){
                  NS_list = sh (
                  script: '''kubectl get ns | awk '{print \$1}' ''',
                  returnStdout: true
                  ).trim()
                  def lst = "${NS_list}";
                      NS = (lst.contains( "${NAME_SPACE}" ));
                      echo "${NS}"
                      if ( NS == true ) {
                         sh "kubectl delete all --all -n ${NAME_SPACE} "
                      }
                      else {
                         sh "kubectl create ns ${NAME_SPACE}"
                      }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared `NS_list`, that will store everything as a string. Add `def NS_list = []` at the beginning of your pipeline

Comment: Not worked :( I placed the def ```NS_list = [ ] ``` above this command ```NS_list = sh (
                  script: .... ```